# Probability of common sequences

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $\textbf{X}, \textbf{Y}$ be two fixed length sequences of length $d_x, d_y$, composed of a language of $K$ symbols. $p(\textbf{X}_i, \textbf{Y}_i = k) = \frac{1}{K}$, and there is no seuquential dependence to the symbols.

What is the probability that $\textbf{X}$ and $\textbf{Y}$ have a common sequence of length $d'$ ($d' \leq d_x,d_y$), not necessarily in an unbroken sequence. Example:

$\textbf{X} = \textbf{1}423\textbf{2}3134\textbf{21}2\textbf{4}211$

$\textbf{Y} = 423\textbf{11}31342211\textbf{4}$

$d_x = 16, d_y = 14, d'=11$. Common sequence: $42331342211$.

Here's what I have so far, but I think I'm missing some things. The probability of any given sequence of length $d'$ is $(\frac{1}{K})^{d'}$. It can occur in any of the sequences ${d_x}\choose{d'}$, ${d_y}\choose{d'}$ times. So the probability that it is common to both of them is ${d_x}\choose{d'}$$*$${d_x}\choose{d'}$$*$$(\frac{1}{K})^{d'^{2}}$. Then, since we don't care about which sequence it is, I think we have to sum over all possible strings, and then we get $d'^K {d_x \choose d'} {d_y \choose d'} K^{-2d'}$.

Comment: Side note: as long as you show what you've tried and/or what your thoughts about the problem are, there is no need to mention that this is not homework (in fact, you are more than welcome to consult here with regards to your homework, and half of the questions on this website probably do exactly that).

Comment: My answer can't be right though, for $d'=1,\ d_x=16,\ d_y=14,\ K=4$ it gives a value greater than 1, so its not a probability. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Any insights why no one is proposing answers to this question?